# create local ubuntu package repository

Tags: repository, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to create an offline package repo for ubuntu 16.04LTS.
I have a repo served out over a small web service, and my sources.list updated to use my local copy.  my sources.list contains the following

```
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://192.168.0.169:8080/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse restricted
```

I am attempting to update the locally installed version of perl for example, the currently installed version is 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 and the version in the Packages file and in the repo is 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6.
apt update successfully finds the correct Package.gz file containing this package, yet when I do an apt list --upgradeable or apt upgrade perl, I am told that the latest version is installed.
What am I missing?

Comment: As this is an OS question and not a programming question, it's most likely more suitable for [ubuntu.se] or [su] rather than here.

Comment: Whoops hopefully it can be moved over there my mistake